# SQL Group by date and sum another col (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I have a datatable and I want to group by different days. But in this column I also have hours, minutes and seconds ...
What I want to do exactly is group by date and sum another column**.

*For example*:

```
Date                       DataToSum
2020-05-20 10:29:37.000        5
2020-05-20 11:18:12.010        3
2020-05-20 12:31:56.020        8
2020-05-21 10:19:36.000        4
2020-05-22 09:28:17.000        1
```

So the results have to be this:

```
2020-05-20 -> 16
2020-05-21 -> 4
2020-05-22 -> 1
```

**How can I do this using SQL?**

I am using ***Transact-SQL*** with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

This is what I am trying:

```
Select distinct convert(varchar, col_Date, 111), Sum(cats) from table1
Group by col_Date
Order by convert(varchar, col_Date, 103) desc
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, Transact-SQL

Comment: You rarely never need to do SELECT DISTINCT when you do GROUP BY, since the GROUP BY eliminates duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  In that database:

```
select convert(date, col_Date) as dte, Sum(cats)
from table1
group by convert(date, col_Date)
order by convert(date, col_Date) desc;
```

The key is that you need to repeat the expression in the `group by`.

Note:  This converts the value to a `date` rather than to a string.  I don't recommend mixing string and date functions, unless you want to convert the date/time to a string with a particular format.

Answer (score 0):

The other option to maybe make it neater and I also find good practice on computed/concatenated columns is a `Common Table Expression (CTE)`

```
With ExampleCTE AS
(
Select  convert(date, col_Date) As dte
,       cats
From    table1
)
Select  dte
,       SUM(cats) As SumOfCats
From    ExampleCTE
Group By dte
Order By dte Desc;
```

Whilst your example is an easy enough one to follow, you may find in the future with more complex scenarios that a `CTE` makes things easier to read